# Can't find method in Angular Service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have written a basic angular JS controller and service to inject in, code as follows.

Controller

```
app.controller("SEFlexHomeController", ["$scope", "$http", "$modal", "$log", "$element", "JobService", "$rootScope", "SEApplicationService", function ($scope, $http, $modal, $log, $element, $rootScope, SEApplicationService) {
        $scope.isDataLoading = false;
        $scope.configvalues = SEApplicationService.getCloudConfigParams();
    }
]);
```

Service

```
app.factory("SEApplicationService", ["$log", "$http", "$timeout", function($log, $http, $timeout) {

    var appService = {};    

    appService.getCloudConfigParams = function () {
        return $http.post("/SEFlex/SEFlexAdmin/GetCloudConfigValues");
    }

    return appService;
}]);
```

And as far as I can understand, this should work. However in the console I can see the error

> Exception was thrown at line 5, column 9 in
>   http://localhost:58270/app/SEFlex/controllers/SEFlexHomeController.js
>   0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'getCloudConfigParams'

I assume I'm doing something basic wrong but I can't see what. Can anyone spot the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to inject one service (`JobService`):

```
app.controller("SEFlexHomeController", ["$scope", "$http", "$modal", "$log", "$element", "JobService", "$rootScope", "SEApplicationService", function ($scope, $http, $modal, $log, $element, JobService, $rootScope, SEApplicationService) {
```

You have the inline typehint but not the param injected in the controller function.

Answer (score 2):

you have missed out injecting JobService proerly. correction -

```
app.controller("SEFlexHomeController", ["$scope", "$http", "$modal", "$log", "$element", "JobService", "$rootScope", "SEApplicationService", function ($scope, $http, $modal, $log, $element, JobService, $rootScope, SEApplicationService) {
        $scope.isDataLoading = false;
        $scope.configvalues = SEApplicationService.getCloudConfigParams();
    }
]);
```